Getting hierachy from 2 columns that have parent child relationships
I have a dataframe like so :
data = {
    'Parent': [None, None,  'A',    'B',    'C',    'I',    'D',    'F',    'G',    'H',    'Z',    'Y',    None,None,None,None,    'AA',   'BB',   'CC',   'EE',   'FF',   None,   None],
    'Child': ['A',  'B',    'D',    'D',    'D',    'C',    'E',    'E',    'F',    'F',    'G',    'H',    'Z',    'Y',    'AA',   'BB',   'CC',   'CC',   'DD',   'DD',   'DD',   'EE',   'FF']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        
   Parent Child
0    None     A
1    None     B
2       A     D
3       B     D
4       C     D
5       I     C
6       D     E
7       F     E
8       G     F
9       H     F
10      Z     G
11      Y     H
12   None     Z
13   None     Y
14   None    AA
15   None    BB
16     AA    CC
17     BB    CC
18     CC    DD
19     EE    DD
20     FF    DD
21   None    EE
22   None    FF

I want an output dataframe like so:

I tried using the networkx package as suggested in this post,
This is the code I used
df['parent']=df['parent'].fillna('No Parent')

leaves =set(df['parent']).difference(df['child'])
g= nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'parent', 'child', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
ancestors = {
    n: nx.algorithms.dag.ancestors(g, n) for n in leaves
}

df1=(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ancestors, orient='index')
 .rename(lambda x: 'parent_{}'.format(x+1), axis=1)
 .rename_axis('child')
 .fillna('')
 )

But I get an empty dataframe.
Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

It looks like you are aiming for a pivot table, have you tried it? pd.pivot

This is the #10 in the duplicate

@Bruno it’s not really a pivot table.  The actual data has  no order to subsequent values of child and parent. I need to look at each value in the child column and find the corresponding parents which may be anywhere in the parent column.

One of the options is to make the final DataFrame from_dict of the predecessors :
DG = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df.fillna("#"), "parent", "child", create_using=nx.DiGraph
)

DG.remove_node("#") # remove the placeholder

out = (
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        {n: DG.predecessors(n) for n in DG}, orient="index"
    ).rename(columns=lambda c: f"Parent {c+1}").reset_index(names="Child")
)

# {"Parent 1": "deepskyblue", "Parent 2": "lightcoral", "Parent 3": "springgreen"}



Thank you for this solution! Is there a way to get the output in the graphical way as you depicted?

Sure, here is the full code (including the visualization part).

Use cumcount to differentiate multiple parents, then pivot.
Use sort_values if you care about the output order, otherwise you can remove it.
out = (
    df.assign(rank=df.groupby("Child").cumcount() + 1)
    .pivot(index="Child", columns="rank", values="Parent")
    .add_prefix("Parent ")
    .sort_values(by="Child", key=lambda col: col.map(lambda x: (len(x), x)))
    .reset_index()
)
out.columns.name = None

   Child Parent 1 Parent 2 Parent 3
0      A     None      NaN      NaN
1      B     None      NaN      NaN
2      C        I      NaN      NaN
3      D        A        B        C
4      E        D        F      NaN
5      F        G        H      NaN
6      G        Z      NaN      NaN
7      H        Y      NaN      NaN
8      Y     None      NaN      NaN
9      Z     None      NaN      NaN
10    AA     None      NaN      NaN
11    BB     None      NaN      NaN
12    CC       AA       BB      NaN
13    DD       CC       EE       FF
14    EE     None      NaN      NaN
15    FF     None      NaN      NaN


What do you mean by grouped? In the example I grouped the order for convenience. The actual table has thousands of rows and values in the child column may be out of order. The only relationship is between the value in the parent column and the value in the child column.

@thentangler I meant all equal childs would have to be in contiguous rows, but that's my mistake, actually. cumcount also works if they're aren't contiguous, so that doesn't matter. I've edited the answer to remove that.

thank you for this option. The output using this method, gives exactly the expected table I had in the screenshot. However I had forgotten to include a row for I where there is no parent. Timeless's solution using networkx seems to have captured the I relationship as well.
